# List of Classes in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have multiple classes (B, C and D) that are subclasses of class A. I need to make a List/Array containing B, C and D and create Objects based on whatever element I pull from the List/Array.

In AS3 I would do something like this: var classes:Array = [MovieClip, Sprite, Shape]; or a Vector of Classes.

How do I do this in Java?
I'm thinking about something like this right now:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> list = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();

list.add(B);
```

Comment: Just like that @Rob, but use `B.class` instead of just `B`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
List<Class<? extends A>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();
classes.add(B.class);
classes.add(C.class);
classes.add(D.class);
```

Comment: Now I understand, I had to use B.class, not B.

Comment: Might I ask how do I then create an Object of the List element?

Comment: You can call `aClass.newInstance()` if the class has a 0 argument (called standard) constructor, otherwise you'll have to use one of the `getConstructors` methods. Checkout http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: Just to inform we need to declare the list just like here its declared as `new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();` . Otherwise exception occurs

Answer (score 4):

You can do analogues of both of those. As [CarlosZ pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613311/list-of-classes-in-java/5613353#5613353), there's [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and its various implementations, or you can create an array:

```
Class[] classes = new Class[] {
    MovieClip.class, Sprite.class, Shape.class
};
```

Comment: Or use `Arrays.<Class<?>>asList(MovieClip.class, Sprite.class, Shape.class);` as an alternative